# Set image src with jquery on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, performance

I am working on a website that has image blocks, with various sizes (relative width based on the current size of the parent, parent also have a relative size to window). I use jquery `load` event to rewrite the `src` attributes of the images based on the image object's dynamic size to ensure pixel perfect view. The problem is that the browser download the full size image, than replace it with a dynamically generated one. This leads to unnecessary loadings and speed loss.

What if I let the `src` value empty, that add the correct url into it? I would like to stay seo optimized, so an empty src maybe not a good idea. Can I achieve this without double downloading images? Maybe I should use an event before the browser begins the download the `src` data.

My code:

```
$('.image').load(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('optimized')) {
        $(this).attr('src', '/image-perfection.php?image=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('src')) + '&width=' + $(this).width());
        $(this).addClass('optimized');
    }
});
```

Comment: But I can not detect the window size on server side, and I would not like to use redirection on the first load. Can I do that somehow without redirection?

Comment: Can you help me how to detect window size on server side?

Comment: I use PHP on my server.

Comment: Derp. A cursory googling has determined that I'm wrong :\ sorry about that... deleting my comments...

Comment: What about using HTML5 appcache or HTTP cache control? You can send the image and cache it or say that it should not be requested again for another week. Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Create a small thumbnail, and let your images to point to the same thumbnail image.

The advantage of this is that you can specify a 'loading' like image that will be pre-catched by the browser for next requests, and then you can load the images the way you do.

You can also write a proxy script that cut the images in the server for you, if you're working with uploaded images you can cut them once they're uploaded for optimize the process, of course it depends of how your implementation must be.

Comment: But if search engines crawl my site, they will see the thumbnail as image data, and this is not good for my site's seo, is it?

Comment: extending edgar's answer with your problem, instead of loading a single thumbnail for everything, you can always load the "mobile" size of your image first and swap it out if you need after loading

Comment: Yes that was my first idea, but I have a lot of images, and to much http requests to use this technique.